# Java doesn't allow arrays of inner classes for a generic class

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I know that you cannot create an array of a generic type, Instead you have to resort to a hack. (Given Java supports generic arrays, just not their creation, it is not clear to me why a hack is better than Java supporting creating generic arrays)

Instead of writing this

```
Map.Entry<K, V>[] entries = new Map.Entry<K, V>[numEntries];
```

you have to write this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map.Entry<K, V>[] entries = (Map.Entry<K, V>) new Map.Entry[numEntries];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if you have an array of nested type of a generic

```
public class Outer<E> {
    final Inner[] inners = new Inner[16]; // Generic array creation

    class Inner {
    }
}
```

The best work around appears to be

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Inner[] inners = (Inner[]) Array.newInstance(Inner.class, 16);
```

Is this the most "elegant" solution?

---

I make seen [Generic Array Creation Compilation Error From Inner Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671723/generic-array-creation-compilation-error-from-inner-class) but the solution here is worse IMHO.

Comment: Your first and second lines of code have something mixed up, I think. `entries` is declared as a (single) `Map.Entry` object, but you are trying to assign an array of `Map.Entry` objects. Also, how can `entries` also be the array dimension?

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you for pointing that out. Right in both cases.

Comment: IMHO the linked solution is best. Is there a reason it has to be an array?

Comment: "`new (Map.Entry<K, V>) Map.Entry[numEntries];`" should be `(Map.Entry<K, V>) new Map.Entry[numEntries];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
final Inner[] inners = (Inner[])new Outer<?>.Inner[16];
```

The equivalent to your first example would have been `new Outer.Inner[16]` but this will isolate the unchecked cast and avoid the raw type.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to realize is that your situation is the same as the first situation you described.

`Inner` is a non-static inner class of `Outer`, a generic class. That means `Inner` is within the scope of the type parameter, and simply writing `Inner` is short for `Outer<E>.Inner`. i.e. it may not look it, but simply `Inner` is a parameterized type, just like `Map.Entry<K, V>`, because the type parameter `E` of the outer class becomes implicitly a type parameter of the inner class. The solution to both problems is the same.

Your solution to the first problem was to create an array of the raw type, i.e. `new Map.Entry[numEntries];`. What is the raw type here? Not `Inner`, as we already discussed. Instead, you need to *explicitly qualify* the outer type to access the raw type: `new Outer.Inner[16];`. Of course, you need a cast to cast it back into the desired generic array type:

```
(Inner[])new Outer.Inner[16]
```

There is another way to create an array of a generic type, without using a raw type -- using a wildcarded type, i.e. `new Map.Entry<?, ?>[numEntries];`. The equivalent for our case would be `new Outer<?>.Inner[16];`. With the cast:

```
(Inner[])new Outer<?>.Inner[16]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it an option for you to make the inner class `static`?

If that is possible you shold be able to create array of the inner class using the standard way:

```
public class Outer<E> {
    final Inner[] inners = new Inner[16]; // works

    static class Inner {
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work by refactoring `Inner` to take an `Outer` as an argument instead of being non-static.