# Cannot create a generic array of OuterClass<T>.InnerClass

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have this code

```
public class OuterClass<T> {
    public OuterClass() {
        InnerClass[] array = new InnerClass[4]; // compile-error
    }

    private class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

which does not compile because of **Cannot create a generic array of OuterClass.InnerClass** in the line where I create the array.

Why is this so and how can I fix/workaround it?

Comment: I'd love to know how this is a duplicate. The linked question is not directly related to this. I don't want to create a generic array.

Comment: AyCe, you're right - it doesn't relate to the duplicate question. I reopened your question accordingly

Comment: Possibly this thread would be helpful, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20475142/java-doesnt-allow-arrays-of-inner-classes-for-a-generic-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InnerClass` is a non-static inner class. Non-static members of `OuterClass` are within the scope of the type parameter `T` of `OuterClass`. This means that **`InnerClass` is implicitly generic**.

Every time inside an instance context of `OuterClass` where you write just `InnerClass`, without explicitly qualifying it, it is implicitly treated as `OuterClass<T>.InnerClass`. So when you wrote

```
InnerClass[] array = new InnerClass[4];
```

the compiler sees it as

```
OuterClass<T>.InnerClass[] array = new OuterClass<T>.InnerClass[4];
//                                                ^
// see? you are using "new" to create an array of a parameterized type
```

Even though the parameter is not physically on `InnerClass`, it is on the `OuterClass`, it is still a type parameter of `InnerClass`, just written in a different position.

Creating an array of a parameterized type, as you may know, is not allowed in Java. Just like how `List<T>[] = new List<T>[4];` is not allowed.

So what's the usual workaround for creating an array of a generic type? You can create an array of the raw type:

```
List<T>[] = new List[4]; // legal
```

or of the wildcard-parameterized type:

```
List<T>[] = (List<T>[])new List<?>[4]; // legal
```

Now back to your problem of the inner class. What is the raw type in this case? It is not `InnerClass`, because as we have seen, it is implicitly parameterized with `T`. We have to *explicitly qualify* `InnerClass` with a raw `OuterClass` to get the raw `InnerClass`:

```
InnerClass[] = new OuterClass.InnerClass[4]; // legal
```

Alternately using the wildcard-parameterized type (again, we have to put the wildcard on `OuterClass`):

```
InnerClass[] = (InnerClass[])new OuterClass<?>.InnerClass[4]; // legal
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Make inner class `static`

```
public class OuterClass<T> {
    public OuterClass() {
        InnerClass[] array = new InnerClass[4];
    }

    private static class InnerClass {

    }
}
```

Comment: beware of statics. They cannot access anything else inside your class. Static classes are instantiated first and their lifetime is the lifetime of the class v. the object. That means that instance variables will not work with your Inner Class

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. InnerClass can hold an instance of OuterClass and can access non-static members of OuterClass via this instance.

Comment: just sounds a bit circular/overcomplicated. I didn't mark down or anything because it could work.

Comment: I know that making the inner class static would work. Your second idea is exactly my current workaround and seems to work pretty well. However, the other answer has exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -3):

you have a paremetization problem. Generics need to now the Type, what it is dealing with. Integer, Double, Float; etc. at compile time. That type trickles down to your encapsulated classes but not in a way specifying the type (outerclass.innerclass) and that is why there is a problem (see newacct).

Therefore, you need to parametize the InnerClass since it has no idea what is being dealt with. Taking the class out of the outer class works.

However,your fix for an inner class is as so.

```
 package quicktest;

 public class OJust<T>{
      public OJust() {
         InnerClass[] array = new InnerClass[4]; // compile-error
     }

     private class InnerClass<T>{

     }
```

}

Comment: This is a terrible idea. The inner class is still parameterized by the outer `T`, but now has a *separate* inner parameter `T` that hides it.

Comment: So it doesn't just inherit whatever was passed for T?